# Need help calculating poisson posterior distribution given prior

Tags: bayesian, poisson-distribution, gamma-distribution

I have been attempting to figure this out for hours, but gamma distribution is somehow beyond me. I have a question where we are given `α=5` and `β=1` for the prior (`Gamma(5, 1)`). We are also given `λ=4` for our poisson distribution and are asked to calculate the value of the posterior and Bayesian Estimate.

So far I attempted this `posterior = P(λ) * Gamma(5, 1) = 24 * .0733 = 1.753`, a formula I found online. However, I have absolutely no idea if this is correct. I don't even know where to start for the Bayesian Estimate. Can someone please help point me in the right direction?

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! Try to express the problem more clearly & explain how far you've got. For a start, write down the prior probability density function for the Poisson mean & the probability mass function for the observed data conditional on that mean.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can read these Wikipedia pages on [conjugate prior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_prior) and [prior probability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prior_probability) first. In short, the posterior probability is the probability of parameters $\theta$ given the data x, or $p(\theta|x)$, and prior probability is a probability about the uncertainty of parameters based on subjective assessment, or $p(\theta)$.

Based on the Bayes' theorem, the relationship between the prior, the posterior, and the likelihood function is
$p(\theta|x) = \frac{p(x|\theta)p(\theta)}{\int p(x|\theta^{`})p(\theta^{`})}$. For certain choices of $p(\theta)$, the posterior and the prior has same algebraic form, and the integral in the denominator has closed form; such $p(\theta)$ is called a conjugate prior. The bottom of the conjugate prior page shows that the Gamma distribution is a conjugate prior of the Poisson distribution.

---

Before computing the posterior $p(\lambda|x)$ with prior $g(\lambda;\alpha,\beta) = \frac{\beta^{\alpha} \lambda^{\alpha-1} e^{-\lambda\beta}}{\Gamma(\alpha)}$ and Poisson pmf $p(x|\lambda)= \frac{e^{-\lambda}\lambda^x }{x!}$, **what are the samples from the Poisson distribution? You need to have some samples drawn from the Poission distribution** to compute the likelihood with them and then compute the posterior.

Suppose the samples are $x = \{x_1, ..., x_n\}$, then $p(x|\lambda) = \frac{\lambda^{\sum{x_i}}* e^{-n\lambda}}{x_1*...x_n}$.  It's too troublesome to type the derivation since the likelihood of Poisson samples is fairly complex. The following derivation considers that there's only one sample x and $p(x|\lambda)= \frac{e^{-\lambda}\lambda^x }{x!}$, and you can derive the posterior for n samples own your own and see if the posterior follows a Gamma distribution with parameters $\alpha + \sum_{i=1}^n x_i ,\ \beta + n\!$ as listed in the first link.

---

$p(\lambda|x)= (\frac{e^{-\lambda}\lambda^x}{x!} * \frac{\beta^{\alpha} \lambda^{\alpha-1} e^{-\lambda\beta}}{\Gamma(\alpha)})\div (\int_0^\infty (\frac{e^{-\lambda}\lambda^x}{x!} * \frac{\beta^{\alpha} \lambda^{\alpha-1} e^{-\lambda\beta}}{\Gamma(\alpha)}) d\lambda)$. The denominator = $\int_0^\infty ( \frac{\beta^{\alpha+x} \lambda^{\alpha+x-1} e^{-\lambda(\beta+1)}}{\beta^x*x!*\Gamma(\alpha)}) d\lambda = \frac{ \Gamma(\alpha +x)}{\beta^x*x!*\Gamma(\alpha)} \int_0^\infty Gamma(\lambda; \alpha + x, \beta+1) d\lambda = \frac{ \Gamma(\alpha +x)}{\beta^x*x!*\Gamma(\alpha)}$.

After canceling some terms in the numerator and denominator, $p(\lambda|x)= \frac{ \beta^{\alpha+x} \lambda^{\alpha+x-1} e^{-\lambda(\beta+1)}}{\Gamma(\alpha+x)} = Gamma(\lambda; \alpha + x, \beta+1)$. Substitute the values $\alpha, \beta, \lambda$ , and x to obtain the posterior probability.

Comment: Thank you so much to taking the time out of your day to thoroughly explain gamma distributions. After doing everything from reading through 2 textbooks to watching a Harvard lecture on the topic, this was the most well worded and helpful thing I've come across

Comment: I solved the same exercise yesterday and got the same answer, but I have a question, if the distribution is Gamma($a+x,\beta+1)$ the pdf should not be $p(\lambda|x)= \frac{ (\beta+1)^{\alpha+x} \lambda^{\alpha+x-1} e^{-\lambda(\beta+1)}}{\Gamma(\alpha+x)} = Gamma(\lambda; \alpha + x, \beta+1)$?

Answer (score 4):

I think the derivation by @Tom is partially correct and there is a value missing from the final expression. 
\begin{align}
\int_0^{\infty}(\frac{\beta^{\alpha}\lambda^{\alpha+x-1}e^{-\lambda(\beta+1)}}{x!\Gamma(\alpha)})d\lambda & = \frac{\Gamma(\alpha+x)}{x!\Gamma(\alpha)}\frac{\beta^\alpha}{(1+\beta)^{\alpha+x}}\int_0^{\infty}\frac{(\beta+1)^{\alpha+x}}{\Gamma(\alpha+x)}\lambda^{\alpha+x-1}e^{-\lambda(\beta+1)}d\lambda \\ 
& = \frac{\Gamma(\alpha+x)}{x!\Gamma(\alpha)}\frac{\beta^\alpha}{(1+\beta)^{\alpha+x}}\int_0^{\infty}Gamma(\lambda;\alpha+x,\beta+1)d\lambda \\
& =   \frac{\Gamma(\alpha+x)}{x!\Gamma(\alpha)}\frac{\beta^\alpha}{(1+\beta)^{\alpha+x}}
\end{align}
I guess this would be the final form.
Now if you plug this as denominator in $p(x|\lambda)$ then after some cancellation we get $Gamma(\lambda ;\alpha+x,\beta+1)$

Comment: Do you mean $Gamma$ or $\Gamma$ instead?

Comment: I used $Gamma$ to denote **gamma distribution** and $\Gamma$ as **gamma function**.

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance!